# How to show Images imported by JSON data

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to get images to show from a url using json. I can retrieve the url but I do not know how to get it to show as a image. Currently the code compiles but returns no images.

I’ve been using this extension

```
extension UIImageView { 
    func load(url: URL) {      
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in 
           if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) { 
              if let image = UIImage(data: data) { 
                  DispatchQueue.main.async { self?.image = image }
              } 
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Comment: The imageUrl is a string and this is the code I put in the list  Image(venues.imageUrl)

Comment: I've also tried to implement this extension extension 

UIImageView {
    func load(url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Add this extension,

```
     func stringToImage(_ handler: @escaping ((UIImage?)->())) {
         if let url = URL(string: self) {
             URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                 if let data = data {
                     let image = UIImage(data: data)
                     handler(image)
                 }
             }.resume()
         }
     }
 }
```